# Change Line Feeds from CRLF to LF in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, newline, line-endings, linefeed, lf

I recently noticed that the line-feeds of files in my project are CRLF but I want them as LF.(I get  the following message from GIT GUI :

> "UTF-8 Unicode text, with CRLF line terminators"

How can I solve  this problem?

Comment: have you tried to change the settings? (`Window->Preferences->General->Workspace: Text File Encoding and the New Text file line delimiter`)

Answer (score 14):

Try this :

```
Window->Preferences->General->Workspace: New Text file line delimiter
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Just try below process

File--> Convert Line Delimiters to --> Unix

Comment: I do not have `Convert Line Delimiters to` menu option.  How do I get this menu option?